# Emscripten - how do I define the getFuncWrapper signature for a C function that takes float**, float** and unsigned long?

Tags: javascript, c, signature, emscripten

Let's say I have a C function with this signature: `void function(float **, float **, unsigned long)`, in code that's ported to JavaScript via Emscripten. This function is to be called from an Emscripten JavaScript library, and must thus be converted to a JS function via Emscripten's Runtime.getFuncWrapper. How do I express the C function signature as a signature string to Runtime.getFuncWrapper?

Comment: Please explain if you downvote... I won't know how to improve the question otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the following signature string works: 'viii'. The first character ('v') describes the function's return type, i.e. `void`, whereas each 'i' represents an argument of `int` type. Pointers are represented as integers, so this should be the correct signature.